# Alter beautifulSoup code to extract words

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, decimal, beautifulsoup

here is some code I found online that will get prices (i.e. decimals) from websites. I need to alter this code so it doesn't return a decimal, but a string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib, string, sys, urllib2, re, time 
start = time.time() 
# Find Bloomberg Brent Price 
rawBloomData = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/energy/").read() 
BloomSoup = BeautifulSoup(rawBloomData) 
brent = BloomSoup.findAll('tr')[14] 
BloomPrice = str(re.search(re.compile (r"\d+\.\d*"),str(brent.contents)).group())
print (BloomPrice)
```

this will return crude oil brent price. I need to grab the word about it which is "price".
when I change the line of code from

```
brent = BloomSoup.findAll('tr')[14]
      to
brent = BloomSoup.findAll('tr')[12]
```

it should return

```
'Price'
```

Comment: What is your question? Your want it to return "Price", but it's not? What is it actually returning?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw I am sorry if I have confused you. I want it to return the actual word price. If you go to http://www.bloomberg.com/energy/ you will see that under the word price, there are actual prices like 62.03, 65034, etc. But I do not want the prices, I want to extract the word "Price" itself.

Comment: I think I got that, but you say that you get the word price by changing the index from 14 to 12, so what's the problem?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw when I run the code with the index at 12, it returns an error because the code is made to only handle decimals, not strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that this line is still looking for decimal numbers of the form `\d+\.\d*`:

```
BloomPrice = str(re.search(re.compile (r"\d+\.\d*"),str(brent.contents)).group())
```

Change your code so that it extracts the third word from the `brent` string instead.

Comment: that is what I am having trouble with. I do not know how.

Comment: it kind of works, but not really. It is further than where I was so thanks.